# How can I auto-close an urxvt terminal after executing an expect script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, automation, expect, rxvt

I've written a script to handle quick copying of passwords to the clipboard:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn -noecho zsh
expect "$ "
send "pass show -c "
interact
exit
```

This script is launched like this:

```
urxvt -e /home/user/pass_script.sh
```

The script runs well, but after finishing, the spawned urxvt terminal needs to close. It doesn't do so as of now. How can I make sure it does?

Comment: does it auto close for other commands like `urxvt -e sleep 5`? if yes, try `urxvt -e expect -d /home/user/pass_script.sh` and see what's the problem.

Comment: That code is fine. The problem, I'm guessing, is what the `pass` command does after you hit enter. Does it ever end?

Comment: @pynexj: yes, it does close after running `urxvt -e sleep 5`. running with debug flag doesn't show me what goes wrong; the script will just copy my password to clipboard and return with a new prompt (instead of exiting). @glenn jackman: well, I have to add my desired password ID after the already entered `"pass show -c "`. After entering my ID, zsh will return with a prompt instead of exiting.

Comment: just replace `interact` with `expect "$ "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn -noecho bash
expect "$ "
send "pass show -c " 
interact -nobuffer \r return
expect "Copied"
sleep 0.05
```